# Gather a ng-model from several input fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angular and i am trying to display several input boxes and then gather the inputs of the user for each. The number or id of the input boxes depends on a json and its dynamic. I am trying to create the structure in a `ng-repeat` but it only displays one input box when i define the field `ng-model` for it.
This is what i have so far.

```
 <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in personType.requirements">
<label for="{{key}}">{{key}}:</label> <input type="text" id="{{key}}" value="{{value}}" ng-model="newReg.{{key}}"></td>
 <td><button id='finalizePerson' ng-click="register(newReg)">Register</button></td>
```

Comment: To use dynamic `ng-model` properties try `newReg[key]` instead

Comment: @RahilWazir It showed all the inputs with that, but when i `console.log` the argument inside the `register` function its undefined.

Comment: You need to explicitly define `$scope.newReg = {};` to your controller scope

Comment: @RahilWazir Thank you that did the trick. Add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly define the `$scope.newReg = {};` to your controller scope.

And to use dynamic `ng-model` properties, try `newReg[key]` instead.